# Replace value in a row based on duplicat ID and delete subsequent rows in R

Tags: r

I have a database with the following structure:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8)
Var1 <- c(1,2,1,2,4,1,2,3,5,4)
Var2 <- c(6,8,7,4,7,8,9,5,7,5)
df <- data.frame(cbind(ID,Var1,Var2))
```

The dataframe looks like this now:

```
   ID Var1 Var2
1   1    1    6
2   2    2    8
3   3    1    7
4   4    2    4
5   4    4    7
6   5    1    8
7   6    2    9
8   7    3    5
9   7    5    7
10  8    4    5
```

I want to replace the Var2 value for the first duplicated ID with the Var2 value from the second duplicated ID (see lines 4:5 and 8:9) and then completely delete the entire row for the second duplicate ID. The final df would look like this:

```
  ID Var1 Var2
1  1    1    6
2  2    2    8
3  3    1    7
4  4    2    7
5  5    1    8
6  6    2    9
7  7    3    7
8  8    4    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (note OP is not specific about more than two duplicates, what this will do is it will take first `Var1` and last `Var2`):

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, list(Var1 = Var1[1], Var2 = Var2[.N]), by = ID]
#   ID Var1 Var2
#1:  1    1    6
#2:  2    2    8
#3:  3    1    7
#4:  4    2    7
#5:  5    1    8
#6:  6    2    9
#7:  7    3    7
#8:  8    4    5
```